# How to get transfer with token USDT of address balance in web3 python in ethereum

Tags: datacontract, code-contracts, web3py, contract

Hi I am trying to get all transfer from USDT Token of 1 Token holder with the following information:

- token contract: 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7
- token holder: 0x28C6c06298d514Db089934071355E5743bf21d60

Here is the link to that transfer: https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0x28c6c06298d514db089934071355e5743bf21d60

`from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

## instantiate a web3 remote provider

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://ethereum-mainnet.s.chainbase.online ...'))

## Tether (USDT) token contract address

token_contract_address = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"

## Replace with the token holder address you want to query

token_holder_address = "0x28C6c06298d514Db089934071355E5743bf21d60"

from web3 import eth_abi

def get_transactions_with_token(web3, token_contract_address, token_holder_address):
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=token_contract_address, abi=ERC20_ABI)

```
transfer_topic = web3.keccak(text="Transfer(address,address,uint256)")

transfer_events = web3.eth.getLogs({
    "address": token_contract_address,
    "topics": [transfer_topic, None, token_holder_address],
    "fromBlock": 0,
    "toBlock": "latest",
    
})

transactions = []
for event in transfer_events:
    decoded_event = eth_abi.decode_log(contract.abi, event.data, event.topics)
    tx_hash = event.transactionHash.hex()
    quantity = decoded_event[2]
    transactions.append({"tx_hash": tx_hash, "quantity": quantity})

return transactions
```

## Replace ERC20_ABI with the ABI (Application Binary Interface) of the ERC-20 token contract.

## You can obtain the ABI from the token contract's official documentation or an Ethereum block explorer.

ERC20_ABI = [{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"stri"type":"event"}]  # Replace with the actual ABI

## Call the function to get the transactions with the specified token contract and token holder

transactions = get_transactions_with_token(w3, token_contract_address, token_holder_address)
print(transactions)`

but i can't get transfer info like in this picture
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a blockchain data indexer to get it without contacting the ABI.

[Bitquery](https://bitquery.io/) has a transfers API and token holders API. For the address you have mentioned, you can get all transfers from this address with this query. There is an auto-code generator that will generate the code in Python for you.
[image]

```
{
  ethereum(network: ethereum) {
    transfers(
      options: {desc: "block.height", limit: 10, offset: 0}
      sender: {is: "0x28C6c06298d514Db089934071355E5743bf21d60"}
      amount: {gt: 0}
    ) {
      block {
        timestamp {
          time(format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }
        height
      }
      sender {
        address
        annotation
      }
      receiver {
        address
        annotation
      }
      currency {
        address
        symbol
      }
      amount
      amount_usd: amount(in: USD)
      transaction {
        hash
      }
      external
    }
  }
}
```

run it [here](https://ide.bitquery.io/Transfers-from-an-address)